# Is possible to capture image and crop it then upload it to firebase in ionic 2?

Tags: camera, ionic2, crop, angularfire2

I searched a lot about the way to capture image by phone camera, then I can crop it, and finally I want to upload croped image on firebase…

Is that possible for ionic 2 ? Or no way to did these three steps togather ?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture an image using the phone camera and crop it and upload to the server. There are two options as follows.

1. https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop
2. https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/ionic-framework-version-2/upload-an-image-to-the-php-server-using-ionic-2-transfer-and-camera-plugin

**Option 1:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Camera, Crop } from 'ionic-native';

@Injectable()
export class CameraService {

  public options: any = {
        allowEdit: true,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
  }

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {}

  // Return a promise to catch errors while loading image
  getMedia(): Promise<any> {
    // Get Image from ionic-native's built in camera plugin
    return Camera.getPicture(this.options)
      .then((fileUri) => {
        // Crop Image, on android this returns something like, '/storage/emulated/0/Android/...'
        // Only giving an android example as ionic-native camera has built in cropping ability
        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
          return fileUri
        } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
          // Modify fileUri format, may not always be necessary
          fileUri = 'file://' + fileUri;

          /* Using cordova-plugin-crop starts here */
          return Crop.crop(fileUri, { quality: 100 });
        }
      })
      .then((path) => {
        // path looks like 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.foo.bar/cache/1477008080626-cropped.jpg?1477008106566'
        console.log('Cropped Image Path!: ' + path);
        return path;
      })
  }

}
```